# How can an object be moved to a new point?

Tags: java, canvas

This code draws a circle in a frame

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Drawing extends Canvas { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Drawing");
        Canvas canvas = new Drawing();
        canvas.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.fillOval(50, 50, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Now how can it be moved to a new point (for example (100,100))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Swing* you don't need a [Canvas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html) to draw shapes. You can extend `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent()` method. Please refer to the following.

1. [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html)
2. [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

All you need to do is change the values of the `x` and `y` coordinates when you call method `fillOval()`. Here is a small application that demonstrates.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Drawing extends JPanel implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private static final String  MOVE = "Move";

    private int  x;
    private int  y;
    private JFrame  frame;

    public Drawing() {
        x = 10;
        y = 10;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
        switch (actionCommand) {
            case MOVE:
                moveCircle();
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                              actionCommand,
                                              "Unhandled",
                                              JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                                          RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    }

    private JButton createButton(String text, int mnemonic, String tooltip) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
        button.setToolTipText(tooltip);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        return button;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.add(createButton(MOVE, KeyEvent.VK_M, "Moves circle."));
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createCanvas() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        return this;
    }

    private void moveCircle() {
        x = 100;
        y = 100;
        repaint();
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Drawing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createCanvas(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Drawing());
    }
}
```

When you run the above code, you will see a blue circle near the top left corner of the application window.

When you click on the **Move** button, you will see the circle drawn in a different location.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setLocation(Point p)` which moves the component to a new location.

In your example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Drawing extends Canvas {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Drawing");
        Canvas canvas = new Drawing();
        canvas.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        canvas.setLocation(new Point(100,100));

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.fillOval(50, 50, 50, 50);
    }
}
```